# How to sort a list of times

Tags: python

I'm just starting out with Python and wondering how I would go about sorting this

list from the earliest time to the latest.

```
('5:00PM','2:00PM','7:00AM','8:45PM','12:00PM')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your work. Also, these aren't a list of times, they're strings.

Comment: What are your sorting conditions? What you are showing is a tuple and not a list. Have you tried to do this yet? Can you show your code?

Comment: Write a function that returns a 24hr equivalent integer of the times in the list then use it as the key function for [list.sort()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)

Answer (score 3):

In python3 with standard library only:

```
import time
hours = ('5:00PM','2:00PM','7:00AM','8:45PM','12:00PM')
format = '%I:%M%p'
time_hours = [time.strptime(t, format) for t in hours]
result = [time.strftime(format, h) for h in sorted(time_hours)]
assert result == ['07:00AM', '12:00PM', '02:00PM', '05:00PM', '08:45PM']
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you install the PyPi [DateTime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime/4.0.1) package and use those facilities for whatever manipulation you desire.  The problem at hand would look something like:

```
stamps = ('5:00PM','2:00PM','7:00AM','8:45PM','12:00PM')
DT_stamps = [DateTime(s) for s in stamps]
DT_stamps.sort()
```

Implementation details are left as an exercise for the student.  :-)

Comment: This doesn't leave the result with a list of sorted strings.

Comment: OP declared them to be a list of times, not strings, so I chose this tack.  If the true problem is to sort strings, then we'll get a clarification to that effect Real Soon Now.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the times are always going to be in that format, you could split the times into subsections.

```
x = "12:30PM"
# Use python's string slicing to split on the last two characters
time, day_half = x[:-2], x[-2:]
# Use python's string.split() function to get the difference between hours and minutes
# Because "11" < "2" for strings, we need to convert them to integers
hour, minute = [int(t) for t in time.split(":")]
# Get the remainder because 12 should actually be 0
hour = hour % 12
# Output it as a tuple, which sorts based on each element from left to right
sortable = (day_half, hour, minute)
#: ("PM", 12, 30)
```

To wrap it all up, use something like:

```
def sortable_time(time_str):
    time, day_half = time_str[:-2], time_str[-2:]
    hour, minute = [int(t) for t in time.split(":")]
    hour = hour % 12
    return day_half, hour, minute

# When sorting, use `key` to define the method we're sorting with
# (The returned list however, will be filled with the original strings)
result = sorted(your_time_list, key=sortable_time)
#: ['7:00AM', '12:00PM', '2:00PM', '5:00PM', '8:45PM']
```

If you're not guaranteed to have the two letters at the end, or the colon in the middle, you're best off using a library like what is suggested by Prune.

Comment: thank you for the response! I believe i'm only allowed to use the standard library.

Comment: No problem @alex756 If any of these responses helped you, don't forget to upvote and mark one of them as correct so others can find the answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you're showing isn't a list of times, it's a tuple of strings. Tuples are immutable and can't be sorted, only mutable collections like lists can be. So first you need to convert your tuple to a list:

```
times = ['5:00PM','2:00PM','7:00AM','8:45PM','12:00PM']
```

You could try sorting this list now, but the strings won't sort the way you expect. Instead, you need to create a custom sort function that will temporarily convert the values in the list to `struct_time` objects and sort using those.

```
import time

time_format = '%I:%M%p' # match hours, minutes and AM/PM

def compare_as_time(time_str1, time_str2):
    # parse time strings to time objects
    time1 = time.strptime(time_str1, time_format)
    time2 = time.strptime(time_str2, time_format)

    # return comparison, sort expects -1, 1 or 0 to determine order
    if time1 < time2:
        return -1
    elif time1 > time2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Now you can call [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and pass in your list and your custom comparison function and you'll get a list of strings back, sorted by the time in those strings:

```
sorted_times = sorted(times, compare_as_time)
```

**Note for Python 3:** The previous example assumes Python 2. If you're using Python 3, you'll need to convert the comparison function to a [`key function`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function). This can be done using [`functools.cmp_to_key()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) as follows:

```
form functools import cmp_to_key

sorted_times = sorted(times, key=cmp_to_key(compare_as_time))
```

Comment: Even in Python2 you can just specify the `key` function. Which would simplify your function to a simple: `sorted(times, key=lambda x: time.strptime(x, time_format))`. Note: I actually don't like `lambdas` but in comments it's hard to `def` functions.

Comment: I intentionally wrote this out long for to illustrate how sorting with a custom comparator works. The OP is trying to learn and apply this so the one liner isn't as helpful.

Comment: If you think it's helpful to illustrate removed features (`cmp` was removed from sorted in Python3) then please add a Warning that the answer only works with python2. The OP did not specify his version so it's at least probable that your answer does not work for him. :-)

Comment: @MSeifert I've updated the answer to include a Python 3 adaptation.